# Gradle - add dependency to tests of another module

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module gradle project that looks like this:

```
Parent
|--server
|--application (android module)
+--common
```

The server tests have a dependency on the common module tests. For this, I added

```
testCompile files(project(':common').sourceSets.test.output.classesDi
compileTestJava.dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':common:testClasses')
```

and it worked great. Unfortunately, when I tried to do the same thing for the application module that also has a dependency on the common module tests, it wouldn't work. It fails with:

```
Build file 'application\build.gradle' line: 103
A problem occurred evaluating project ':application'.
 Could not find property 'sourceSets' on project ':common'
```

After googling a bit I also tried

```
 project.evaluationDependsOn(':common')
    testCompile files(project(':common').sourceSets.test.output.classesDir)
```

But fails with another exception:

```
Project application: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: common\build\classes\test
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches solving the problem of importing test classes in this article. https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2014/09/07/gradle-sub-project-test-dependencies-in-multi-project-builds/ The one I used is:

code in shared module:

```
task jarTest (type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    classifier = 'test'
}

configurations {
    testOutput
}

artifacts {
    testOutput jarTest
}
```

code in module depending on the shared module:

`dependencies{
    testCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: 'testOutput')
}`

And there seems to be a plugin for it as well! https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.hauner.jarTest/1.0

Comment: Works like a charm @sakis kaliakoudas

Comment: when I define the new task I get an error : "Could not get unknown property 'test' for SourceSet container" but I don't know what does it mean

Comment: @Apperside Check the [answer by droidpl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36062014/1427177) which does not throw that error.

Answer (score 7):

Following the approach from sakis, this should be the configuration you need to get the tests available from another project in the Android platform (done for debug variant).
Shared module:

```
task jarTests(type: Jar, dependsOn: "assembleDebugUnitTest") {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/test/debug"
}
configurations {
    unitTestArtifact
}
artifacts {
    unitTestArtifact jarTests
}
```

Your module:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(path: ":libName", configuration: "unitTestArtifact")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's kinda an old question but the solution mentioned in the following blog  solves the problem very nicely and is not a sort of hack or a temporary workaround:
[Shared test sources in Gradle multi-module project](https://vkuzel.com/shared-test-sources-in-gradle-multi-module-project)

It works something like this:

```
// in your module's build.gradle file that needs tests from another module
dependencies {
    testCompile project(path: ':path.to.project', configuration: 'test')
}
```

Also you should note that in the very last paragraph he mentioned that you need to enable **Create separate module per source set** in IntelliJ settings. But it works fine without using that option too. Probably due to changes in the recent IntelliJ versions.

**EDIT**: IntelliJ recognizes this fine as of 2020.x versions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Says 'Could not resolve project ':my-project' even though I'm depending on it successfully for non-tests.

Answer (score 3):

The solution mentioned by [droidpl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36062014/5864033) for **Android + Kotlin** looks like this:

```
task jarTests(type: Jar, dependsOn: "assembleDebugUnitTest") {
    getArchiveClassifier().set('tests')
    from "$buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debugUnitTest"
}

configurations {
    unitTestArtifact
}

artifacts {
    unitTestArtifact jarTests
}
```

Gradle for project that is going to use dependencies:

```
testImplementation project(path: ':shared', configuration: 'unitTestArtifact')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use gradles [java test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures). This will automatically create a `testFixtures` source set, in which you can write your test that you want to reuse.

> Test fixtures are configured so that:
>
> - they can see the main source set classes
> - test sources can see the test fixtures classes

For example, if you have some class in common module:

```
public class CommonDto {
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;

    // getters/setters and other methods ...
}
```

Then in the common module, you could write into `src/testFixtures/java` following utils:

```
public class Utils {
    private static final CommonDto A = new CommonDto(1, "A");
    private static final CommonDto B = new CommonDto(2, "B");

    public static CommonDto a() { return A; }

    public static CommonDto b() { return B; }
}
```

Then in you other modules you could add this to reuse `Utils` class

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies ...
    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":common")))
}
```

All of this is better explained in the documentation that I provided initially. There are some nuances that you need to take into account until you create this not to leak test classes into production.

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me.  I tried this one last, since it was light on detail, but it's the one that worked.  The various posts and SO answers wound up not being as helpful as going to the docs directly:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures